# Are there other uses for the Elder Scroll?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim I've finished the main quest but I still have the Elder Scroll. There's a funky visual effect when I try to read it but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there any point hanging on to it now (maybe there's another special location where something happens if you read it there?) or should I just store it or sell it?

Comment: Since they are indestructible, you could use them as an armor. ☺

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can donate it to the Orc Librarian in the College Of Winterhold, for about 2000 gold and his eternal gratitude.
Aside from that I don't think there is anything you can do with it.

Answer (score 7):

The elder scroll you gain from the main quest is now used in the Dawnguard DLC as well. If you sold it to the orc you'll have to buy it back from him for 4000 gold. You also gain two more elder scrolls. The new two can be sold to the Moth Priest for 6000 gold in the Dawnguard DLC if you sided with the Dawnguard. Alternatively you can just give him the scrolls for free (much to his astonishment).

Comment: I have three scrolls and they are using up 60 weight in my pack. I can't stash them. The orc doesn't have a dialog option to take them and the priest isn't in the Dawnguard fortress. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: The item has a stated weight of 20 each but in actuality they weigh nothing and don't contribute to your encumbrance. If you can't find the priest or sided with the vampires, you cannot remove them.