# What can we do after opening the elder scroll on the Throat of the World?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I opened the elder scroll and saw the ancient nords. But after killing a dragon, nothing happened and I could just look around. What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug that also happened to me. You simply have to reload from your last save and watch "the movie" again. :)

Comment: The bug happened to me too. What's supposed to happen is that Alduin lands in front of the heros and fights them, but due to a glitch this doesn't always work, and you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

((SPOILER))

> you are to do absolutely nothing. You are only suppose to watch the past dragonborns use the dragonrend shout. From there one you will be led to learn the shout and use it  to defeat alduin

Answer (score -1):

It's useless after completing that quest, as you can sell it to the orc in the Winterhold library for 2000 gold.

Comment: He's asking when he used the elder scroll and looked in the past, nothing happened. He isn't saying what should I do with the scroll after using it in the Time Wound since I can't drop it. The question you're supposed to be answering is: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46284/are-there-other-uses-for-the-elder-scroll